# How to check which field is used where before deleting those fields?

Tags: custom-field

I have to delete some fields on Account object.But before delete,I want to investigate whether these fields used.e.g.The field could refer somewhere in apex class,VF,WF rule,Formula field,Territory etc.

Is there any automotive way where I can find out where the field is referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_references.htm&type=5
such information is availbe on salesforce "Where Used" tab.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option would be to look for an app from appexchange, like [Field Dependency Finder](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5ekWEAR). There could be many others, got this from first google search.

Other option could be to search for the field Name in a IDE like eclipse or mavensmate, for this you need to retrieve all components in your IDE.

Ugliest solution would be to actually try deleting the field to see the dependency.

Comment: Eclispse is another option where I can search where the field is referred... Below is the link of how to search in Eclispse:                                                             https://teachmesalesforce.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/searching-metadata-with-the-ide/